# Como traduzir "fazer impressão" para o inglês?

Tags: tradução-inglês

Como traduzir “fazer impressão”, que [significa](https://dicionario.priberam.org/Fazer%20impress%C3%A3o) “meter medo ou causar mal-estar”, para o inglês?

Por exemplo:

> "Eu não posso olhar para a minha ferida porque faz impressão"
>
> "Eu não posso olhar para objetos afiados porque me faz impressão”

Comment: Coolguy, poderias nos dar o significado da expressão? Não a conhecia. Se bem entendi o Priberam, traduziria como “I can't (even) look at a knife that it makes me sick” ou “I can't (even) look at a knife that I get/feel sick” ou afins.

Comment: Se mudares um pouco a estrutura da frase, podes dizer _I'm squeamish about the sight of the wound_.

Comment: I can't look at my wound because it makes me squeamish.

Comment: Traduções estão dentro dos tópicos desta página

Answer (score 1):

Em registos informais pode usar "freaks me out" para "mete-me medo" ou "grosses me out" para "da-me nojo". Há outras da forma "____ me out". São muito informais, mas têm um papel importante, porque frases mas formais como "scares me", "frightens me" e "disgusts me" têm um ar de seriadade que não se encaixa bem em certos contextos sociais.

Answer (score 0):

A frase “fazer impressão”, pode significar algo do tipo: "Eu não posso olhar para a minha ferida porque ela tem mal aparência" ou " "Eu não posso olhar para a minha ferida porque me incomoda".